# Strapi using Stripe Payments -> Cant upload image: 403 error

Tags: token, strapi, headless

Strapi with Stripe Payment plugin won't let me upload and image file for the product.

"Uploading File" indicator spins forever.

Checking console logs I get a 403 error.  I know this is a permission error, but I am new to Stapi and I can't find much help that explicitly guides me through setting up the permissions.

I created a "strapi-admin" token in Strapi as instructed and put in the `.env` the
`STRAPI_ADMIN_API_TOKEN=xxxxxxx`

I was able to create products after Payment Config, however, I was not able to upload an image, hence the 403 upload error.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Here is a dump of the console log from the browser in the strapi admin config console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
/admin/settings/strapi-stripe:1 Refused to load the image 'https://higheredlab.com/wp-content/uploads/hel_icon.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: blob: https://market-assets.strapi.io".

/admin/settings/strapi-stripe:1 Refused to load the image 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dvotpztje/image/upload/v1671441868/paypal-logo_tifrf5.webp' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: blob: https://market-assets.strapi.io".

/api/upload:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
[request].a3b68b11.chunk.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at De ([request].a3b68b11.chunk.js:25:9708)
```

Comment: I was able to check the javascript and looks like it referenced a BASE_URL .env variable, which I then updated, and it took care of some of the console log errors I posted. Still no go on the image upload.